# Automation without api

Tags: automation

Noob programming question. We have a closed source program (erp system) that we would like to automate some data entry functions. This application does not have an API. Is my only option to write something with sendkeys and tab my way thru the application? 
I know a little python and vbs/vba.

Comment: autohotkey is the standard solution for that: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: testcomplete has a wide range of tools (window mapping, entering text, clicking, etc..) for automation without api, yet it costs a lot :)

Comment: Rekin - excellent suggestion I had not run into Autohotkey before.

Comment: Shookees - I like it but....their not going to give me any money. Big surprise I know.